# How to translate this piece of code from Java to Kotlin?

Tags: android, inheritance, kotlin

I'm trying to translate this piece of code from Java to Kotlin. However, I'm struggling with the "super" call of the second constructor that receives an integer as argument.

```
package info.androidhive.volleyexamples.volley.utils;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageCache;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

public class LruBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements
        ImageCache {
    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        return cacheSize;
    }

    public LruBitmapCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public LruBitmapCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }
}
```

I've done this so far. As you can see, LruCache obligates you to pass something as argument. But I want to calculate this argument with the method "getDefaultLruCacheSize".

```
class LruBitmapCache(var maxSize: Int = 0) : LruCache<String, Bitmap>(maxSize), ImageCache {

    private fun getDefaultLruCacheSize(): Int {
        val maxMemory = (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024).toInt()
        return maxMemory / 8
    }

    init {
        maxSize = getDefaultLruCacheSize()
    }

    override fun sizeOf(key: String?, value: Bitmap?): Int = if (value != null) {
            (value.rowBytes * value.height / 1024)
        } else{
            val defaultValue = 1
            defaultValue
        }

    override fun getBitmap(url: String?): Bitmap? = get(url)

    override fun putBitmap(url: String?, bitmap: Bitmap?) {
        put(url, bitmap)
    }
```

The problem is that with my current approach, the super is called before my init method.

Comment: in android studio, if its inside of a .kt file, doesnt it change it to kotlin?

Comment: @soldfor I don't know if I used it badly, but it doesn't worked as I expected. Also, I'm trying to learn Kotlin, so writing manually can be useful.

Comment: @Leonardo Rocha. Consider coping your Java code base and pasting it Android studio should give you the option to convert the code base to kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@JvmOverloads` and use a default value for your cache, so you do not need a 2nd constructor defined explicitly:

```
class LruBitmapCache @JvmOverloads constructor(
        sizeInKiloBytes: Int = defaultLruCacheSize
) : LruCache<String, Bitmap>(sizeInKiloBytes), ImageCache {

    protected fun sizeOf(key: String, value: Bitmap): Int = value.rowBytes * value.height / 1024

    fun getBitmap(url: String): Bitmap = get(url)

    fun putBitmap(url: String, bitmap: Bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap)
    }

    companion object {
        val defaultLruCacheSize: Int
            get() {
                val maxMemory = (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024).toInt()

                return maxMemory / 8
            }
    }
}
```

If you want to use a 2nd constructor, you need to do this

```
class LruBitmapCache(
        sizeInKiloBytes: Int
) : LruCache<String, Bitmap>(sizeInKiloBytes), ImageCache {

    constructor(): this(defaultLruCacheSize)

    // omitted for brevity
}
```